# How to use default iOS camera controls with react-native-camera

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-camera

Is there a way to use the default iOS camera controls with [react-native-camera](https://react-native-camera.github.io/react-native-camera/)? Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[image: default ios camera controls]

I'd like to use this standard iOS UI for taking a photo, toggling front/back camera, toggling flash, etc, and not create buttons for each of those from scratch. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here: [react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker) is a better choice for this task. It lets the user either pick a photo from their camera roll OR use the native camera (with default iOS controls) to take a photo.